# React-Boostrap [set dropdown menu width to the same size as dropdown when changes]

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

iam trying to set the dropdown menu width dynamically to the exact same size like the whole dropdown, when it changes. How do i get the width oft the dropdown itself?

I also tried to align the dropdown menu to the "end" what caused it to be right aligned. In this case filling the remaining space to the left side is the problem.

I tried different approaches and failed with them. Has somebody an idea ho to get this done?

What am i doing wrong?

```
import React from 'react';
import {Col, Container, Dropdown, Row} from 'react-bootstrap';

class SelectComp extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        id: 1,
    };
}

render() {
    return (
            <div>
                <Dropdown align="end">
                    <Dropdown.Toggle variant="outline-success" id="dropdown-basic">
                        Exposure Type: {
                            {
                                '1': 'Eins worked',
                                '2': 'Zwei worked',
                                '3': 'Drei worked',
                            }[this.state.id]
                        }
                    </Dropdown.Toggle>
                    <Dropdown.Menu>
                        <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => {
                            this.setState({id: 1});
                        }}>1</Dropdown.Item>
                        <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => {
                            this.setState({id: 2});
                        }}>2</Dropdown.Item>
                        <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => {
                            this.setState({id: 3});
                        }}>3</Dropdown.Item>
                        <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => {
                            this.setState({id: 4});
                        }}>4</Dropdown.Item>
                        <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => {
                            this.setState({id: 5});
                        }}>5</Dropdown.Item>
                        <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => {
                            this.setState({id: 6});
                        }}>6</Dropdown.Item>
                        <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => {
                            this.setState({id: 7});
                        }}>7</Dropdown.Item>
                        <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => {
                            this.setState({id: 8});
                        }}>8</Dropdown.Item>
                        <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => {
                            this.setState({id: 9});
                        }}>9</Dropdown.Item>
                        <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => {
                            this.setState({id: 10});
                        }}>10</Dropdown.Item>
                        <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => {
                            this.setState({id: 11});
                        }}>11</Dropdown.Item>
                        <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => {
                            this.setState({id: 12});
                        }}>12</Dropdown.Item>
                        <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => {
                            this.setState({id: 13});
                        }}>13</Dropdown.Item>
                        <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => {
                            this.setState({id: 14});
                        }}>14</Dropdown.Item>
                        <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => {
                            this.setState({id: 15});
                        }}>15</Dropdown.Item>
                        <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => {
                            this.setState({id: 16});
                        }}>16</Dropdown.Item>
                        <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => {
                            this.setState({id: 17});
                        }}>17</Dropdown.Item>
                        <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => {
                            this.setState({id: 18});
                        }}>18</Dropdown.Item>
                        <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => {
                            this.setState({id: 19});
                        }}>19</Dropdown.Item>
                        <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => {
                            this.setState({id: 20});
                        }}>20</Dropdown.Item>
                    </Dropdown.Menu>
                </Dropdown>
            </div>
    )
}
}

export default SelectComp;
```

Comment: Do you want to have the dropdown menu the same size as toggle or vice versa? What ist this " Exposure Type..."-text in the toggle? How is your state defined? Can you provide a fully WORKING example?

Comment: Exactly. The text (also size) of the toggel changes by selection of some dropdown item. So the dropdown menu has to be the same size. But i dont know how to get the exact width from the toggle. I changed the code above to a working example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your outer container inline-block and give the dropdown menu 100% width. for example:

```
 <Dropdown className="d-inline-block">
 ...
    <Dropdown.Menu className="w-100">
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-galois-z2xnlk

Comment: That works kind of, i got only a problem under an specific amount of width, so the scrollbar sticks out.

I used:
`.dropdown-menu {
height: auto;
max-height: 140px;
overflow-x: hidden;
    }`


https://i.imgur.com/8jVtXye.png

https://i.imgur.com/Tq2RZPV.png

Comment: These styles are not in the initial question, so I couldn't know. What do you expect in this case anyway?

Comment: I thought it would be great if the overflow part ist alltime lined up with the end of the toggle instead of sticking out when the width gets too small.

But i got the solution, it was the min-width that had to set to auto, so im fine with that. Thank you for helping.